# cant import dependency implementation on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, datetimepicker, android-library, jitpack

I am beginner to android studio and I am trying to import a remote dependency for a library of DatePickerDialog ([link for its github](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)) but the import doesn't work for me.

I tried to import it by the Group Id (com.github.wdullaer) and Artifact Name (MaterialDateTimePicker) as it shows in the ProjectStructure/dependencies

I tried - import com.github.wdullaer.MaterialDateTimePicker

I also tried - import com.wdullaer.MaterialDateTimePicker

and more but the import does not work
but

here is my gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is the DateTimePicker implementation:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.speedq"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.wdullaer:MaterialDateTimePicker:v4.2.3' // this is the implementation I cant import

}
```

if any one knows how can I import it it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is wrong:

```
implementation 'com.github.wdullaer:MaterialDateTimePicker:v4.2.3'
```

first of all dont use `v` near version, so just remove it

also you got wrong path, read again [guide](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) - you should use this:

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
```